How to change the color of the active button to custom?
Changing the color of the active pagination button in NextUI
I'm trying to change the color of the active button in the pagination component of the NextUI library to a specific HEX code #2D3748. However, the library does not allow using HEX codes directly through the color property.
I have created the following code for the pagination component but I am not able to achieve the desired result.
 <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
      <Pagination
        total={10}
        color="#2D3748"
        page={currentPage}
        onChange={setCurrentPage}
        className={styles.customPagination} // Використання кастомного класу
      />
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <Button
          size="sm"
          variant="shadow"
          color="secondary"
          onPress={() => setCurrentPage(prev => (prev > 1 ? prev - 1 : prev))}
        >
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button
          size="sm"
          variant="shadow"
          color="secondary"
          onPress={() => setCurrentPage(prev => (prev < 10 ? prev + 1 : prev))}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>

